# Style not being picked up WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to set up styles in an external DLL that will be used to define how certain controls should look.

I have a resource dictionary defined in an external DLL that has a style targeted at TextBoxes:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="TextStyle">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Moo"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I then reference this built DLL in another application. This works:

```
<Window x:Class="HTMLTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/GX3Resources;component/Resources.xaml"/>

            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,217,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This does not:

```
<Window x:Class="HTMLTest.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Window.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/GX3Resources;component/Resources.xaml"/>

                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Window.Resources>

        <Grid>
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,217,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

I would hope the above would pick up the TextStyle as is it a text box and the style is targetted at textboxes.

Comment: What do you mean by explicitly setting the style? Do you mean setting it via `Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}"` or do you mean copying the style into the TextBox? The code you provided should work.

Comment: The code I have provided does work. WIll update question slightly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can edit the original style, you can use it for all Textboxes automatically by setting its key property to the target type:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}">
```

If you can't change the style, try to create another one based on it:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource TextStyle}" 
       x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}">
</Style>
```

Comment: This may be what my question was about. Let me check then I'll mark as answer

Comment: @user589195 I added another option in case you can't edit the external Dll.

Comment: Looks like it to me. Because you set the key on the style resource to something that's not the TextBox's type, it will never apply implicitly no matter where you define it.